# PowerBI Natural Left outer join issues with deleted rows in right table

Tags: left-join, powerbi, dax

I have two tables.

1) Table 1 : 1 column with date value
2) Table 2 : 2 columns : Date column + business value column

I am trying to use DAX in PowerBI to create a new table using a left outer join to fill missing dates in my second table.

First table :

```
| Date       |  
| 2015-05-01 |
| 2015-06-01 |
| 2015-07-01 |       
| 2015-08-01 |
```

Second table :

```
| Date       | Value    | 
| -----------|--------- |
| 2015-05-01 |        5 |    
| 2015-05-01 |        5 |    
| 2015-06-01 |        6 |    
| 2015-07-01 |        7 |
```

DAX code to create new table :

```
Table = 
var table4=
SELECTCOLUMNS(Table1, "Date", Table1[Date]&"")
var table5=
SELECTCOLUMNS(Table2,"value", Table2[value],"Date", Table2[Date]&"")
return
NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(table4,table5)
```

This is returning :

```
| Date       | Value    | 
| -----------|--------- |
| 2015-05-01 |        5 |    
| 2015-06-01 |        6 |    
| 2015-07-01 |        7 |    
| 2015-08-01 |        NA|
```

But I want:

```
| Date       | Value    | 
| -----------|--------- |
| 2015-05-01 |        5 |    
| 2015-05-01 |        5 |    
| 2015-06-01 |        6 |    
| 2015-07-01 |        7 |    
| 2015-08-01 |       NA |
```

I am not sure why it is removing the second value of

```
| 2015-05-01      5|
```

I need the two values for the month of may to remain in the table.
Any ideas ? thanks a lot

Comment: show your real script.

Comment: What does DAX Studio trace tell you? PS A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including intialization so it is easy for others to reproduce your example & to show your really got claimed output from claimed input.

Comment: @philipxy thanks for your comment. I haven't used Dax studio yet but will download it now to see if I get any messages. As for the minimal reproducible example, i entered the data manually in PowerBi to create Table 1 and 2. Then, to merge the two tables together, I went to the modelling tab, clicked on new table and used the DAX code I posted in the question. Is there anything missing to reproduce this example? thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted Microsoft development team in August, 2019 (via Marco Russo at [SQLBI](https://www.sqlbi.com/)); they confirmed that this behavior was caused by a bug, and promised to fix it in the upcoming releases.

I have tested November, 2019 release of Power BI Desktop and confirm that the bug is indeed fixed.

My test code:

```
T1 = DATATABLE("Date", INTEGER, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}})

T2 = DATATABLE( "Date", INTEGER, "Value", INTEGER, {{1, 5}, {1,5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}})

Test = 
  VAR T3 = SELECTCOLUMNS(T1, "Date", T1[Date]*1)
  VAR T4 = SELECTCOLUMNS(T2, "Date", T2[Date]*1, "Value", T2[Value])
RETURN 
  NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(T3, T4)
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/naturalinnerjoin-function-dax

It joins on the natural columns the rows which matches both and then adds extra columns.

You need to ask yourself why you need this row in your data because when your model is correct, Power-Bi will do the work for you. In your situation you would generate one extra row for each date where a value does not exist, do you need this?

I created your use case and made the correct model:
[image]

next I created a table with dates and values and selected on Date: Select values with no date:

[image]

It is just how you want to present your data.. I do a summary over the values which fall on the same date..

Comment: But the question is why their code as given, which has (aparently) neither relationship nor lineage, acts as it does.

Comment: I have already read that & other documentation. That link is for naturalinnerjoin not left. It agrees with the asker, not the result, since it says an inner join is done. However the corresponding naturalleftouterjoin documentation says that that returns "A table which includes only rows from rightJoinTable for which [..,]" which is not clear about what exactly is returned. Anyway for inner join (an SQL notion) duplicates input give duplicates output. Also that source is wrong/incomplete because it says that inputs must have lineage on common columns. That documentation is not helpful.