# How can I return my value from a column created a conditional column?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm having the following problem, I want to return as a result the value of a column in Power Query but I can't do it.

I need to know how I am able to show as a result the value of the column.

```
Table.AddColumn(
"Result", each if [Price] > 15 then "[Price] Is greater than 15")
```

[Price] doesn't show me the value of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert [Price] to text first:

```
Table.AddColumn(
"Result", each if [Price] > 15 then Text.From([Price]) & " Is greater than 15")
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind my asking about a different but deleted post of yours--Why did you delete [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56624527/3404097)?

Comment: @philipxy - after I'd posted the answer, I contacted Microsoft Power BI development team to confirm that it's correct. To my surprise, they responded that it's a bug. Their answer contradicted my research, so I took the answer down. Two days ago Microsoft notified me that the bug has been fixed. I will wait for the next PBI version to confirm, and then will change and un-delete the answer.

Comment: Wow thanks. I downloaded your references & other documentation, but I never got to reading it to have an interpretation of what the specified behaviour was. Please @ me when you undelete.

Comment: @philipxy - I undeleted the answer; confirmed that the bug is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Still hope at some point to investigate the documentation you linked to (hopefully better than the poor learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax) & also your earlier disavowed reasoning.